# SSH Port-forwarding in KVM/Virtmanager

Tags: ssh, networking, kvm, virt-manager

I am running a guest machine *Debian Stable* with KVM *virtmanager for GUI* on another Debian 9. What I am trying to do is ssh from host to guest. I have the SSH server running and configured on the guest except for forwarding port 22 to the guest.

How can I do this? I know how to do it in VirtualBox but virtmanager is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

There is no graphical tool to handle port forwarding in virt-manager/qemu. The process of forwarding is done using `iptables` DNAT rules.

Qemu provides a hook that is called when starting / stoping guest, which can be used to trigger setting/removing the `iptables` rules, as described here under the [Forwarding Incoming Connections section of Libvirtd's Networking page](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections).